# A better way of optimizing for permutation of function compositions over an input?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of functions and their 'apply priority'.

It looks like this. Length of it is `33`

```
listOfAllFunctions = [ (f1, 1)
                     , (f2, 2)
                     , ...
                     , ...
                     , (f33, 33)
                     ]
```

What I want to do is generate a list of permutations of the above list with no duplicates and I only want 8 unique elements in the inner list.

Which I'm implementing like this

```
prioratizedFunctions :: [[(MyDataType -> MyDataType, Int)]]
prioratizedFunctions = nubBy removeDuplicates
                     $ sortBy (comparing snd)
                    <$> take 8
                    <$> permutations listOfAllFunctions
```

where `removeDuplicates` is defined like

```
removeDuplicates a b = map snd a == map snd b
```

Lastly I'm turning the sublists which'd be `[(MyDataType -> MyDataType, Int)]` to a composition of functions and a `[Int]`

with this function

```
compFunc :: [(MyDataType -> MyDataType, Int)] -> MyDataType -> (MyDataType, [Int])
compFunc listOfDataAndInts target = (foldr ((.) . fst) id listOfDataAndInts target
                                  , map snd listOfDataAndInts)
```

Applying the above function like this `(flip compFunc) target <$> prioratizedFunctions`

---

All of the above is a simplified version of the actual code but it should provide the gist it.

---

The problem is that this code takes practically forever to execute. From some prototyping I think the blame of it falls on my implementation of `permutations` function inside `prioratizedFunctions`.

---

So I was wondering, is there a better way of doing what I want (basically generating permutation of `listOfAllFunctions` where each list only contains 8 elements, every list of elements sorted by their priority with `snd` and containing no duplicate list)

or is the problem inherently a long process?

Comment: You could certainly do it faster than with permutations, you'll get a lot of duplicates when you only take the first 8 elements.  Basically, you want 33 choose 8, instead of 33 choose 33.  Look around for a combinatorics library or algorithm and see if that helps.

Comment: @bheklilr Would it be something like this                                                            `choose 0 xs = [[]]`
`choose n [] = []`
`choose n (x:xs) = map (x:) (choose (n-1) xs) ++ choose n xs`.                                                           Will it have the same effect as the function I used in my question?

Comment: If you want them sorted at the end, don't permute them in the first place...

Comment: @atis I'd honestly just use a library like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/combinat, but that's just me.

Comment: Am I looking at the right function? Because I was looking around the library you suggested, it seems like it implements choose function just like the one I wrote above. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/combinat-0.2.9.0/docs/src/Math.Combinat.Sets.html#choose

Comment: Then you should be all set, I just meant that I'm lazy and for stuff like this I'm less worried about figuring it out myself and more interested in correctness. If you came to the same solution on your own, then awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was generating unnecessary permutations.

This `choose` function is basically a non-deterministic `take` function

```
 choose 0 xs = [[]] 
 choose n [] = [] 
 choose n (x:xs) = map (x:) (choose (n-1) xs) ++ choose n xs
```

which improved performance by a lot.